# C++ Issue with a else if and else statement executing together

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm learning C++ and I'm working on a project that ask a question and leads you to another question. Like a text adventure. I'm have an issue in particular part where when you answer the question in an **if** or **else if statement** the else statement also runs.

What I'm trying to do is have the person answer the question then go to the next question. If the person answer other then the multiple choice question they get an error. I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

   char ch1;
   char q2;
   char q3;

   //// Question 1  
   std::cout << "Welcome to My Program. \n";
   std::cout << "Everyday we wake up in a particular mood that leads our day for the most part. \n";
   std::cout << "Which mood are you waking up to? \n \n";
   std::cout << "A.) Angry \n";
   std::cout << "B.) Blah \n";
   std::cout << "C.) Happy \n";

   std::cin >> ch1;

   if (ch1 == 'a' || ch1 == 'A') { /// question 2
       std::cout << "We are off to a bad start, Everyone sucks. \n\n";
       std::cout << "What are you going to do next to change your day? \n";
       std::cout << "A.) GO GET COFFEE!! \n";
       std::cout << "B.) Just Go to Work \n";
       std::cout << "C.) Go Back To Sleep \n";

       std::cin >> q2;
   } else if (ch1 == 'b' || ch1 == 'B') { /// question 3
       std::cout << "Nothing seems to motivate you and all you want to do is lay in bed. \n";

       std::cout << "What are you going to do next to change your day? \n";
       std::cout << "A.) GO GET COFFEE!! \n";
       std::cout << "B.) Ditch work to go to the beach! \n";
       std::cout << "C.) Go Back To Sleep \n";

       std::cin >> q3;
   } else if ( ch1 == 'c' || ch1 == 'C') {
       std::cout << "Nothing Can Ruin Your Day!! \n";
       std::cout << "ENJOY!!";
   } else  { 
       std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice";
   }

   /// Question 2
   if (q2 == 'a' || q2 == 'A') {
       std::cout << "Things Look Better, You might survive";
   } else if (q2 == 'b' || q2 == 'B') {
       std::cout << "You're a Ticking Time Bomb!";
   } else if ( q2 == 'c' || q2 == 'C') {
       std::cout << "Nothing can beat sleep!!" ;
   } else {
       std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice" ;
   }

   ///Question 3
   if (q3 == 'a' || q3 == 'A') {
       std::cout << "Things Look Better, You might survive";
   } else if (q3 == 'b' || q3 == 'B') {
       std::cout << "You're day Just got Better! Enjoy!" ;
   } else if ( q3 == 'c' || q3 == 'C') {
       std::cout << "Nothing can beat sleep!!" << std::endl; 
   } else {
       std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice";
   }
}
```

Comment: You seem to believe that if you don't assign a value to, say, `q2`, then the program would somehow magically skip all `if (q2 ...)` checks and associated statements. That's not how it works. If you want to skip a section of code, you need to write a conditional statement that executes that section of code only when some condition is true.

Comment: Think about the possible values of `q2` and `q3` if your program reaches the line you marked `Question 2`. Also think about, whether both of them can be initialized if your program reach this point. Then look at the if/else statement blocks below.

Comment: You should be able to simplify to a [mre] by reducing the I/O. Replace each block of streaming to/from `cout`/`cin` with two lines: a summary output like `std::cout << "Question 1\n";` and an assignment like `q2 = 'A'; // hardcoded response for this example`. That will help you and us focus on the logic instead of seeing a wall of text. Please then provide the expected and actual output, given the simplified example. *It might also help to reduce the example to 2 questions instead of 3.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask which of the questions (q2 or q3) were answered:

```
int main () {

   char ch1;
   char q2 = 0;  //// Not answered yet
   char q3 = 0;  //// Not answered yet

   //// Question 1  
   std::cout << "Welcome to My Program. \n";
   std::cout << "Everyday we wake up in a particular mood that leads our day for the most part. \n";
   std::cout << "Which mood are you waking up to? \n \n";
   std::cout << "A.) Angry \n";
   std::cout << "B.) Blah \n";
   std::cout << "C.) Happy \n";

   std::cin >> ch1;

   if (ch1 == 'a' || ch1 == 'A') { /// question 2
       std::cout << "We are off to a bad start, Everyone sucks. \n\n";
       std::cout << "What are you going to do next to change your day? \n";
       std::cout << "A.) GO GET COFFEE!! \n";
       std::cout << "B.) Just Go to Work \n";
       std::cout << "C.) Go Back To Sleep \n";

       std::cin >> q2;
   } else if (ch1 == 'b' || ch1 == 'B') { /// question 3
       std::cout << "Nothing seems to motivate you and all you want to do is lay in bed. \n";

       std::cout << "What are you going to do next to change your day? \n";
       std::cout << "A.) GO GET COFFEE!! \n";
       std::cout << "B.) Ditch work to go to the beach! \n";
       std::cout << "C.) Go Back To Sleep \n";

       std::cin >> q3;
   } else if ( ch1 == 'c' || ch1 == 'C') {
       std::cout << "Nothing Can Ruin Your Day!! \n";
       std::cout << "ENJOY!!";
   } else  { 
       std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice";
   }

   if (q2 != 0)  // If q2 was answered
   {
       /// Question 2
       if (q2 == 'a' || q2 == 'A') {
           std::cout << "Things Look Better, You might survive";
       } else if (q2 == 'b' || q2 == 'B') {
           std::cout << "You're a Ticking Time Bomb!";
       } else if ( q2 == 'c' || q2 == 'C') {
           std::cout << "Nothing can beat sleep!!" ;
       } else {
           std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice" ;
       }
   }
   else  // If q3 was answered
   {
       ///Question 3
       if (q3 == 'a' || q3 == 'A') {
           std::cout << "Things Look Better, You might survive";
       } else if (q3 == 'b' || q3 == 'B') {
           std::cout << "You're day Just got Better! Enjoy!" ;
       } else if ( q3 == 'c' || q3 == 'C') {
           std::cout << "Nothing can beat sleep!!" << std::endl; 
       } else {
           std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice";
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
#include <iostream>


int main () 
{

char ch1;
char q2;
char q3;

//// Question 1  
std::cout << "Welcome to My Program. \n";
std::cout << "Everyday we wake up in a particular mood that leads our day for the most part. \n";
std::cout << "Which mood are you waking up to? \n \n";
std::cout << "A.) Angry \n";
std::cout << "B.) Blah \n";
std::cout << "C.) Happy \n";

std::cin >> ch1;

if (ch1 == 'a' || ch1 == 'A') /// question 2
{
 std::cout << "We are off to a bad start, Everyone sucks. \n\n";
 std::cout << "What are you going to do next to change your day? \n";
 std::cout << "A.) GO GET COFFEE!! \n";
 std::cout << "B.) Just Go to Work \n";
 std::cout << "C.) Go Back To Sleep \n";

 std::cin >> q2;
}

else if (ch1 == 'b' || ch1 == 'B') /// question 3
{
std::cout << "Nothing seems to motivate you and all you want to do is lay in bed. \n";

 std::cout << "What are you going to do next to change your day? \n";
 std::cout << "A.) GO GET COFFEE!! \n";
 std::cout << "B.) Ditch work to go to the beach! \n";
 std::cout << "C.) Go Back To Sleep \n";

 std::cin >> q3;

}
else if ( ch1 == 'c' || ch1 == 'C')
{
std::cout << "Nothing Can Ruin Your Day!! \n";
std::cout << "ENJOY!!";
}
else 
{ 
 std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice 0";
}

/// Question 2
if (q2 == 'a' || q2 == 'A')
{
 std::cout << "Things Look Better, You might survive";
}
else if (q2 == 'b' || q2 == 'B')
{
 std::cout << "You're a Ticking Time Bomb!";
}
else if ( q2 == 'c' || q2 == 'C')
{
 std::cout << "Nothing can beat sleep!!" ;
}
else
{



    ///Question 3
    if (q3 == 'a' || q3 == 'A')
    {
     std::cout << "Things Look Better, You might survive";
    }
    else if (q3 == 'b' || q3 == 'B')
    {
     std::cout << "You're day Just got Better! Enjoy!" ;
    }
    else if ( q3 == 'c' || q3 == 'C')
    {
     std::cout << "Nothing can beat sleep!!" << std::endl; 
    }
    else 
    {
     std::cout <<"Error, Not A Choice 2";
    }
}

}
```

You need to check whether q2 or q3 is answered so you need to put q3 in the else (error case for q2). So if q2 is neither "a","b" or "c" it goes next to check whether q3 is "a" or "b" or "c" and than the error case.
Hope this clears some things out . You might need to look into switch statements next :))